# Controlling Relay Using Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I tried to make a program that can control a 4 channel relay (with LEDs as indicators) with a serial monitor. First time I tried to program it using a `char` command to make it turn on only, it worked. Then I tried to make it off only, it also worked, but when I tried to combine them, to control it to On or Off in the same program, it didn't work.

this is my code

```
#define CH1 2  
 #define CH2 3 
 #define CH3 4 
 #define CH4 5
  void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600);


pinMode(CH1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(CH2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(CH3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(CH4, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(CH1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(CH2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(CH3,HIGH);
digitalWrite(CH4,HIGH);
 }

 void loop (){
  if (Serial.available()) {


char ser = Serial.read();


 switch(ser){ 
 case 'on1':

 onPin1();

 break;


 case 'on2':

 onPin2();

 break;


 case'on3':

 onPin3();

 break;


 case 'on4':

 onPin4();

 break;

 case 'off1':

 offPin1();

 break;


 case 'off2':

 offPin2();

 break;


  case'off3':

 offPin3();

 break;


  case 'off4':

 offPin4();

 break;







   }



 }
 }

 void onPin1(){
    digitalWrite(CH1, LOW);
 }
  void onPin2(){
   digitalWrite(CH2, LOW);
 }
   void onPin3(){
   digitalWrite(CH3, LOW);
 }
  void onPin4(){
   digitalWrite(CH4, LOW);
 }

  void offPin1(){
   digitalWrite(CH1, HIGH);
 }
   void offPin2(){
   digitalWrite(CH2, HIGH);
 }
   void offPin3(){
   digitalWrite(CH3, HIGH);
 }
   void offPin4(){
   digitalWrite(CH4, HIGH);
 }
```

with that code, I got "duplicate value", maybe because the pin is double-called. But when I tried to make it in separate swicth case condition, no error but couldn't respond to the command `char`

Answer (score 1):

This is `C++`, so the single quotes are used for character literals. If you want string literal, you have to use double quotes. However, string literals can't be used in `switch`.

And you can't definitely use it like that if you are reading only one character.

However you can use single characters for this:

```
#define CH1 2  
#define CH2 3 
#define CH3 4 
#define CH4 5

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(CH1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CH2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CH3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CH4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CH1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CH2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CH3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CH4,HIGH);
}

void loop (){
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char ser = Serial.read();
    switch(ser){ 
      case '1':  onPin(CH1); break;
      case '2':  onPin(CH2); break;
      case '3':  onPin(CH3); break;
      case '4':  onPin(CH4); break;
      case '5': offPin(CH1); break;
      case '6': offPin(CH2); break;
      case '7': offPin(CH3); break;
      case '8': offPin(CH4); break;
    }
  }
}

void onPin(int8_t pin) {
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}

void offPin(int8_t pin) {
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
}
```

Or you can toggle the relay states.

Test strings as commands are little bit harder to use as you have to read whole command (or use state machine). Following example is little bit unnecessary hard but it's working...

```
constexpr uint8_t     channels = 4;
constexpr uint8_t ch[channels] = { 2, 3, 4, 5};

template <uint8_t pin, uint8_t val> void setChan() {
  digitalWrite(pin,val);

  Serial.print("setChan: "); Serial.print(pin);  Serial.print(' ');  Serial.println(val);
}

using action_t = void(*)(void);

action_t  on_actions[channels] = {
  &setChan<ch[0],LOW>,
  &setChan<ch[1],LOW>,
  &setChan<ch[2],LOW>,
  &setChan<ch[3],LOW>
};

action_t off_actions[channels] = {
  &setChan<ch[0],HIGH>,
  &setChan<ch[1],HIGH>,
  &setChan<ch[2],HIGH>,
  &setChan<ch[3],HIGH>
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);

  for (auto pin : ch) {
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  }
}

String command = "";
action_t action = nullptr;


void loop() {
  if (action != nullptr) {
    action();
    action = nullptr;
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    if ((inChar == '\r' || inChar == '\n')) {
      if (command.length() > 0) {
        Serial.print(command);
        if (command.startsWith("on")) {
          uint8_t channel = command.substring(2).toInt()-1;
          if (channel < channels) {
            action = on_actions[channel];
          }
          Serial.print(" On="); Serial.print(channel+1);
        } else if (command.startsWith("off")) {
          uint8_t channel = command.substring(3).toInt()-1;
          if (channel < channels) {
            action = off_actions[channel];
          }
          Serial.print(" Off="); Serial.print(channel+1);
        }
        Serial.println();
        command = "";
      }
    } else {
      command += inChar;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have learned about switch case purposes, I i do like that, but I need to use specific "text" instead of single text 't'. How to do that? @kiiv